# How to make HC05 bluetooth module undiscoverable or limited discoverable

Tags: bluetooth, hc-05

I want my HC05 module to be pairable only within a time window of pressing a button (connected to an Atmega328 which talks to the HC-05). This is a pretty normal way for most bluetooth devices i've used like headsets etc. Is there a way to make this happen with HC05?

Scrounging the net, I found that it is called LDM (Limited Discoverability Mode). But i couldn't find anything that told me how to get it done on HC05. I scanned through the [AT commands set](http://www.linotux.ch/arduino/HC-0305_serial_module_AT_commamd_set_201104_revised.pdf) too, with no luck.

Comment: You could power-off the module, until the button is pressed? Then check if a connection is made within the timeframe, and otherwise power off again

Comment: That should work i guess. Will implement it and see.